# Format to output a string and a value in Fortran

Tags: format, fortran, output

I'm making a code in Fortran and I want that it reads input values from a file in this way

```
READ(5,*)IDIAM,ISET
```

and I want to write them to an open file. I wrote this code

```
 WRITE(36,*)'IDIAM',IDIAM,'ISET',ISET
```

which works but it writes all things on a single line. I want to have for each output line only a string and a variable without repeating the write line in the code (because I have  many variable). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely, if you use list-directed output (which is the effect of the `*` in the `write` statement) then the compiler is left with a lot of flexibility on how the output looks ("may" and "reasonable" are terms used in the specification of it).  This conflicts with what is here: some specific control is wanted.

The specific control is when a new record is started.

Typically, a record corresponds to a whole line.  That means you want to write each string/value pair to individual records.  Having one `write` statement for each pair manages that, but is precisely what you don't want.

To use a single `write` statement, the answer is to use an explicit format.  Something like

```
write(36,'(A,1X,I0)') 'IDIAM',IDIAM,'ISET',ISET
```

so that when a pair has been written the record ends.

I've assumed from the variable names, for simplicity, that the variables are integers.  If they aren't, then consider using generalized editing (using `G`).  Also there's the slash edit descriptor (`/`) which forces a new record which can be useful when there's a pattern: note that the format `'(A,1X,I0,/,A,1X,I0)'` would have the same effect as above in the specific case that there are two pairs to write.

Following IanH's correction to the '/' format above, I'm prompted to mention colon editing and repeat specifiers.  As noted, the statement

```
write(36, '(A,1X,I0,/)') 'IDIAM',IDIAM,'ISET',ISET, ...
```

terminates a record on format reversion (when the `)` is reached).  This may result in blank lines between each pair: one for the `/` and one for the end of format.  So, a closer match to the first format using `/` is

```
write(36, '(*(A,1X,I0,:,/))') 'IDIAM',IDIAM,'ISET',ISET, ...
```

Which is quite silly compared with the original, but the power of this approach is hopefully clear.

See documentation for details of explicit formats in general.

Comment: It works thank you but if the variables are in different format how can i force all them to be write as a real (for example) ?

Comment: If you want to write all as a real you could `write(...) 'IDIAM', REAL(IDIAM)` (etc., that is return a real representation) with an appropriate real-type edit descriptor (`F`, `E`, ...).  However, list-directed input won't need a consistent format and your list-directed output will have different formats for each type.  So, I'd recommend using `G` edit which will then also handle things like logical types will clean code.  [That's the point of generalized editing.]